# Jquery .click() not working multiple button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I want show alertbox on click button but more of button the some ID attr and work click on first button but not working click on second button.

**Jquery;**

```
jQuery("#submit").click(function(e){
     alert("message");
});
```

**HTML;** (Repeat html per message)

```
 <div class="reply">
   <form id="vivam" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"> 
      <textarea name="reply" placeholder="Write reply here"></textarea>
      <p class="stdformbutton">
          <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reply</button> 
      </p>
   </form>
 </div>
```

[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/43Fyx/)

What is the solution to this problem? Thank you in advance for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1:** IDs should be unique, use class instead of id.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="reply">
<form id="vivam" method="post" onsubmit="return false;"> 
  <textarea name="reply" placeholder="Write reply here"></textarea>
  <p class="stdformbutton">
      <button class="btn btn-primary submit">Reply</button> 
  </p>
 </form>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(".submit").click(function(e){
 alert("message");
});
```

**[Working Demo Approach 1](http://jsfiddle.net/m336D/)**

**Approach 2:** You can also use attribute value selector to target element with same id. However this breaks the rule `ids should be unique`.and i do not recommend you using this:

```
jQuery("[id=submit]").on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); 
 alert("test");
});
```

**[Working Demo Approach 2](http://jsfiddle.net/tBsz4/)**

Answer (score 1):

ID Must be unique .

Handler get attached to the first element with the id only.

Use `class` instead of `id` .

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/LA62s/)</kbd>

Change HTML

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary submit">Reply</button>
//                                 ^ add class submit and remove id submit
```

Comment: But not possible because must be repeat the form per data

Answer (score 0):

Make it

```
jQuery(".submitbuttons").click(function(e){
```

and then

```
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitbuttons">Reply</button>
```

and please give unique ids and I recommend to set the button-type attribute (button or submit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on`  listener in `JQuery`. That way you listen on an class, and then do something with the id...

Here's an [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPvr6/2/) of the working code...

The HTML ( note that i've changed the ID's because ID's need to be unique, and add the class to the buttons ):

```
<div class="reply">
    <form id="vivam_1" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
        <textarea name="reply" placeholder="Write reply here"></textarea>
        <p class="stdformbutton">
            <button id="button_1" class="btn btn-primary submit">Reply</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="reply">
    <form id="vivam_2" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
        <textarea name="reply" placeholder="Write reply here"></textarea>
        <p class="stdformbutton">
            <button id="button_2" class="btn btn-primary submit">Reply</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JQuery part:

```
$('body').on('click', '.submit', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Clicked on button " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```